# Comparing a cell to a range of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, phpexcel

i am trying to create a program in excel to compare a cell, b13, to a range  of data.

the range of data is: 3.01-3.09 (J8-J16), all of these values are set to 2.95 in a another column of cells.

i need to compare b13, to this range of data above, and return the value 2.95 in D13, if b13=any number in the range of data, it should print the values 2.95 in the cell L8, else the program should run another if function comparing b13 to another range of data 3.10-3.19 (J17:J26) etc for another 4 ranges of data, else if this is not true it should compare b13 to the cell J67 (holds the number 4.00). printing 2.5 as the result.

Hope someone can help me solve this problem as i have been stuck on this for hours.

cheers

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? This place isn't really a do-it-for-me kind of place. Sounds like you can use MATCH.

Comment: tried many times to do it, just gave a lot of background information to allow other people to understand my problem to allow the to help me.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the result in cell D13 or cell L8 and that's before we get to else...

Comment: sorry the result needs to be in d13, thanks

Comment: Can you please share with us the formulas you've tried, and any errors/issues?

Comment: i have tried =if(INDEX(match(value,value,value)>0,"Data Error")

Comment: Excel would instantly balk at that formula...Index requires two arguments and your parentheses count is off. Please enter the real formula you have tried, complete with the actual arguments (instead of "value, value, value")